# Does a Mesos slave needs to be contacted by a Mesos master?

Tags: apache-zookeeper, high-availability, mesos, mesosphere

Can Apache Mesos 'slave' nodes be located on a separate network than the Mesos 'master' nodes? Similarly (for high-availability (HA) deploys), can the Apache Zookeeper nodes used in Mesos 'master' election be deployed on a separate network than the Mesos 'slave' nodes?

Currently, I have 3 masters+slaves nodes in the cloud, and I want to add a slave installed in my local subnet.

If such a setup is feasible, what are the pros/cons of such a setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think https://www.stratio.com/blog/mesos-multi-data-center-architecture-for-disaster-recovery/ is a nice read on several of the things you need to make this work. There are some scenarios on how to handle stuff if a DC is down.

Pros:

- You can failover in case of a DC being down/unreachable

Cons:

- Both DC's must be able to run the environment by itself (active, or you should be able to scale up fast), so that creates overhead costs
- Complexity increases (network, mesos/application configuration)

About the networks: they must be able to connect somehow, so public (but encrypted and firewalled, I also think that every node needs a public IP) or via an ipsec tunnel or another option like the link mentions.
I don't think doing it via the internet without tunneling (so the first option I mention) is a very good option.